# Mostrar mensajes de validación básicos en el campo de texto

Tags: javascript, html5

Quiero mostrar los mensajes de validación debajo de los campos de textos que lo requieran así como el ejemplo que esta en la imagen que encontré

**Ejemplo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo los siguientes campos de texto en mi formulario, con su respectiva validación hecha en **Javascript**

```js
//Funcion para validar formulario de tickets 
function validate_form() {
    valid = true;

    if (document.ticketForm.matricula.value == "") {
        alert("Verifique los datos nuevamente, ingrese la matricula");
        valid = false;
    }

    if (document.ticketForm.nombre.value == "") {
        alert("Verifique los datos nuevamente, ingrese el nombre del solicitante");
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form name="ticketForm" method="post" onchange="validate_form();">
                <div id="informacionTicket" class="user">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ticketIdAppliInput">Matrícula:</label>
                                    <input maxlength="9" required id="ticketIdAppliInput" type="text" name="matricula" onkeypress="if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) return false;" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ticketNameAppliInput">Nombre completo:</label>
                                    <input maxlength="100" id="ticketNameAppliInput" type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ticketEmailAppliInput">Email:</label>
                                    <input maxlength="100" id="ticketEmailAppliInput" type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Lo que no quiero es que se me muestren esos `alert` molestos en la parte superior del formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que se muestre el mensaje como en la imagen de ejemplo

**UPDATE:**

Cuando sigo escribiendo en los demás campos se duplica el mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
    //Funcion para notificar
    function notificacion(el,msg){
      // agrega un elemento p con el texto luego del input seleccionado
      if(!$(el).next().is("p")){
       $(el).after(`<p>${msg}</p>`);
      // elimina el mensaje luego de 2 segundos
      setTimeout(function(){ $(el).next().remove();}, 2000)
      }
    }

    //Funcion para validar formulario de tickets
    function validate_form() {
        valid = true;
        input = document.ticketForm;
        if (input.matricula.value == "") {
            notificacion(input.matricula,"Verifique los datos nuevamente, ingrese la matricula");
            valid = false;
        }
        
        if (input.nombre.value == "") {
            notificacion(input.nombre,"Verifique los datos nuevamente, ingrese el nombre del solicitante");
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid;
    }
```

```css
form p {
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <form name="ticketForm" method="post" onchange="validate_form();">
                    <div id="informacionTicket" class="user">
                        <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="mb-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="ticketIdAppliInput">Matrícula:</label>
                                        <input maxlength="9" required id="ticketIdAppliInput" type="text" name="matricula" onkeypress="if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) return false;" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="ticketNameAppliInput">Nombre completo:</label>
                                        <input maxlength="100" id="ticketNameAppliInput" type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="ticketEmailAppliInput">Email:</label>
                                        <input maxlength="100" id="ticketEmailAppliInput" type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Enviar</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Me indicas en que parte coloco `form p {
   color:red;
}`

Comment: debes agregarlo en el css :v

Comment: Probé tu respuesta y se me duplica el mensaje, revisa la actualización que acabo de hacer

Comment: con la edición que acabas de hacer ya no se muestra el mensaje

Comment: ya lo corregi es que en modo edicion no se puede probar el codigo bien

Comment: No quisiera dejarle un tiempo para quitar el mensaje, quisiera que al dar click sobre el campo que se esta requiriendo automaticamente se quite el mensaje

Comment: eliminas el `seTimeout` y programas un evento `click!`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98914/discussion-between-sebastian-salazar-and-bryro).

Comment: Elimine el setTimeout y el mensaje ya no se borra incluso colocándole los datos